# provide circular motion for a custom drawing on touch: Android

Tags: android, user-interface, ondraw

I have a custom drawn rectangle which i want to move in a circular path based on touch events.
It follows the direction of the touch for clockwise or anticlockwise movement but basically move in circular motion, as if moving on the edge of the circle.

My current thought process is as follows:
Based on the users current and previous x,y i shall find the angle in degrees and then move this rectangle by the same angle by re-drawing in the new position, just making sure that it moves on the edge of a circle.
But this leads  to some confusion on the following:
1. how do i decide whether angle movement is clockwise or anti-clockwise. 
2. I am not being able to figure out the math for this properly.

Would this be the best approach or is there a better idea for doing this?
Also, if this is the best approach, could someone please tell me the formula for calculating the angle by which i should move it  while taking care of the clocking and anticlockwise ?

could someone please help?
please let me know if any more details are required.
Thanks

Comment: Just clarifying: what you want is your rectangle to move along the edge of a set (not moving!) circle either clockwise or anticlockwise, depending on the user's tap. Is that correct?

Comment: yes sir, based on the user's tap and drag motion, the rect should move clockwise or anticlockwise. basically in the same direction as the user's movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Steps

Here are a few steps in order to move your rectangle along a circle's rim **when the user taps and holds** to the side of the circle:
 **1.** Obtain direction desired.
 **2.** Obtain angle from current x and y coordinates.
 **3.** Add direction (+1 if counterclockwise, -1 if clockwise) to angle.
 **4.** Calculate new x and y coordinates.
 **5.** Update/display rectangle.

#### Details

**1.** In pseudocode, `direction = sign(Rectangle1.x - UsersFingerPosition.x)`. Here sign is a function returning -1 if the number was negative, 0 if it is 0, and 1 if it is positive. Note that `sign(0)` will only result when the user is on the exact x and y of your rectangle's location. In that case, the rectangle would not move (which should be good). In Java, the sign function is `Math.signum()`.

**2.** To obtain the current angle use the following java code:

```
double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(Circle.y-Rectangle1.y, Rectangle1.x-Circle.x));
```

Note the order of `Circle.y-Rectangle.y` and `Rectangle.x...Circle.x`.  This is a result of the coordinate (0, 0) being in the top left corner instead of the center of the screen.

**3.** Simple enough, just add direction to angle. If desired, do something like

```
angle += direction*2; //So it will move more quickly
```

**4.** To get the new x and y coordinates of your rectangle, use the trigonometric functions sine and cosine:

```
Rectangle1.x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))*Circle.radius + Circle.x - Rectangle1.width;
Rectangle1.y = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))*Circle.radius + Circle.y - Rectangle1.height;
```

(where Circle.x and Circle.y are the coordinates of the center of your circle and Circle.radius is naturally it's radius).

**5.** This one you'll have to take care of (or have already) :)!

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks. in #2 should it not be (usersfingerposition.y, usersfingerposition.x), otherwise angle will always be the same?

Comment: I'm sorry about #2, I messed it up! However, it should not be `users...` because `angle` is the angle from the center of the circle to the (x,y) coords of the rectangle. In that way you can 'rotate' the angle, which would move the rectangle around the circle. I'll edit #2 so that it is correct.

Comment: hello, there is small issue with the above steps. where do u calculate the angle moved when the finger moves. only if we have that angle, then only we would be able to find the new x,y for the rectangle based on #4. so where do u find the angle moved by the finger

Comment: I realized that you want the user to *drag* the rectangle along the circle, right? Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking! My solution works very well if you **tap** and hold on either side and have the rectangle move!! I'm sorry! I'll add another answer for dragging!

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps

Here are a few steps in order to move your rectangle along a circle's rim:
 **1.** Obtain finger position/Check that it's still dragging the rectangle.
 **2.** Obtain angle from current x and y coordinates.
 **3.** Calculate new x and y coordinates.
 **4.** Update/display rectangle.

#### Details

**1.** This one is probably specific to your code, however, make sure that when the user starts dragging the rectangle, you set a variable like `rectangleDragging` to `true`. Before you run the next steps (in the code), check that `rectangleDragging == true`. Set it to `false` once the user lets go.

**2.** To obtain the current angle use the following java code:

```
double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(Circle.y-Finger.y, Finger.x-Circle.x));
```

Note the order of `Circle.y-Finger.y` and `Finger.x...Circle.x`.  This is a result of the coordinate (0, 0) being in the top left corner instead of the center of the screen.

**3.** To get the new x and y coordinates of your rectangle, use the trigonometric functions sine and cosine:

```
Rectangle1.x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))*Circle.radius + Circle.x - Rectangle1.width;
Rectangle1.y = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))*Circle.radius + Circle.y - Rectangle1.height;
```

(where Circle.x and Circle.y are the coordinates of the center of your circle and Circle.radius is naturally it's radius). Subtracting the width and height of the rectangle should center it on the circle's border instead of placing the left, upper corner on the circle.

**4.** This one you'll have to take care of (or have already) :)!

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I have one add on question. The circle one which i am moving the rectangle is a arc of 300 with max and min points on either ends. I want to stop clockwise movement after max is reached and stop any further CCW movement after min is reached. is there a quick way to do this

Comment: Yeah, just find the angles you want the rectangle to stop at and add an `if (angle >= 120){ angle = 120; }` with 120 replaced by the angles you want. You'll need two of those `if`s.